# tool to generate class diagrams

Tags: java, uml

I have a number of java files and would like to generate the class diagrams showing the methods and members in it. Which one is the best tool for doing this? Could you please provide me the names for both free and commercial tools?

Answer (score 1):

The [eUML2](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/com.soyatec.uml.doc/) plugin for Eclipse works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

[BOUML](http://www.bouml.fr/index.html) does the trick... But beware! It used to be open source until version 5.0. But it is not anymore.

Comment: It is back free of use since the 7.0

Answer (score 1):

[Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html) is a commercial tool.

My free favorite used to be JUDE, now [Astah](http://astah.net/download#community).

UML is pretty useless.  When I need diagrams, I usually generate them from my code using [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).  It has both community and enterprise editions.